# Regex to parse phone numbers in text document with java

Tags: java, html, regex

I'm trying to use regex to find phone numbers in the form (xxx) xxx-xxxx that are all inside a text document with messy html.

The text file has lines like:

```
  <div style="font-weight:bold;">
  <div>
   <strong>Main Phone:
   <span style="font-weight:normal;">(713) 555-9539&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
   <strong>Main Fax:
   <span style="font-weight:normal;">(713) 555-9541&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
   <strong>Toll Free:
   <span style="font-weight:normal;">(888) 555-9539
```

and my code contains:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\(\\d{3}\\)\\s\\d{3}-\\d{4}");
Matcher m = p.matcher(line); //from buffered reader, reading 1 line at a time

if (m.matches()) {
     stringArray.add(line);
}
```

The problem is when I put even simple things into the pattern to compile, it still returns nothing. And if it doesn't even recognize something like \d, how am I going to get a telephone number? For example:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+"); //Returns nothing
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d");  //Returns nothing
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\s+"); //Returns lines
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\D");  //Returns lines
```

This is really confusing to me, and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Matcher#find()` instead of `matches()` which would try to match the complete line as a phone number. `find()` would search and return `true` for sub-string matches as well.

```
Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
```

Also, the line above suggests you're creating the same `Pattern` and `Matcher` again in your loop. That's not efficient. Move the `Pattern` outside your loop and reset and reuse the same `Matcher` over different lines.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\(\\d{3}\\)\\s\\d{3}-\\d{4}");

Matcher m = null;
String line = reader.readLine();
if (line != null && (m = p.matcher(line)).find()) {
    stringArray.add(line);
}

while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
  m.reset(line);
  if (m.find()) {
    stringArray.add(line);
  }
}
```

Comment: This was the solution. Thanks for clarifying the difference between find() and matches().

Answer (score 2):

Or instead of regexp you can use Google library - libphonenumber, just as follows

```
    Set<String> phones = new HashSet<>();
    PhoneNumberUtil util = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();

    Iterator<PhoneNumberMatch> iterator = util.findNumbers(source, null).iterator();

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        phones.add(iterator.next().rawString());
    }
```